Out-of-order delivery TCP
I have some questions about out-of-order delivery in a TCP diagram. In the diagram (picture below), you can see the connection between the Client and the Server. Which variant is correct, A or B? In variant A, the Server sends an ACK with AN=101 (the number of the out-of-order packet), or is it like in variant B?
I also have one more question. When we send a FIN with packet 5, and the Server responds with an ACK to the Client, does the connection close immediately, and will we still receive packet 4 after that?
How does FIN work?


A FIN from one side just means that side is done sending, but it can still receive until the other side also sends a FIN and it gets acknowledged. RFC 9293, Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), Section 3.2.2, State Machine Overview has a good description and diagram of the TCP state machine.

TCP provides a byte stream without gaps and the ACK presents the last position received in this stream. Any data arriving out of order of this stream (i.e. which would produce a gap) are not yet part of the (gapless) stream and thus will not (yet) be acknowledged.
In your specific case it got the byte stream up to sequence 101 in step 6, i.e. the packet 5 starting with sequence 151 does not matter because the preceding data were not received. In step 6 the missing data were received (by getting packet 4) and thus the stream is complete until 201, which is ACKed in 7.

When we send a FIN with packet 5, and the Server responds with an ACK to the Client, does the connection close immediately,

A FIN only signals that the sender will not send any more data. But the connection is only actually closed if both sides have stopped sending, which means both sides have sent the FIN.
For more on this see a TCP state diagram, for example this here from Wikimedia Commons

